# Capistrano install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I try install capistrano gem in my project and catching error:

> uninitialized constant Capistrano::Configuration::SSHKit (NameError)

Full log:

```
bundle exec cap install
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/server.rb:4:in `<class:Configuration>': uninitialized constant Capistrano::Configuration::SSHKit (NameError)
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/server.rb:3:in `<module:Capistrano>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/server.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/configuration.rb:4:in `require_relative'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/configuration.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/filter.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/filter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:5:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/all.rb:11:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/lib/capistrano/all.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/bin/cap:2:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.9.1/bin/cap:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/cap:22:in `load'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/cap:22:in `<main>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Ubuntu server 16.04
Ruby 2.4.0
Rails 5.1.4

How fix it?

**UPD 1**

```
ubuntu@rails-serv-1:/var/www/cargo$ bundle exec gem list cap ssh

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

capistrano (3.9.1)
capistrano-bundler (1.3.0)
capistrano-rails (1.3.0)
capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
capistrano3-puma (3.1.1)
capybara (2.15.2)
invisible_captcha (0.9.3)

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

airbrussh (1.3.0)
net-ssh (4.2.0)
sshkit (1.14.0)
```

Comment: Can you include the output of this command? `bundle exec gem list cap ssh`

Comment: @MattBrictson  I add output.

Comment: Do you already have a `Capfile` in your project? If so, remove it before running `bundle exec cap install`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @MattBrictson No I have not Capfile in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Capistrano version and `bundle exec cap install` works fine for me.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

capistrano (3.9.1)

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

airbrussh (1.3.0)
net-ssh (4.2.0)
sshkit (1.14.0)
```

My only guess is that the additional `capistrano-` gems that you have in your Gemfile are causing the problem.

If you have not already done so, I recommend adding `require: false` to your Gemfile for *all* Capistrano-related gems.

E.g.

```
gem "capistrano", require: false
gem "capistrano-bundler", require: false
gem "capistrano-rails", require: false
gem "capistrano-rvm", require: false
gem "capistrano3-puma", require: false
```

Also, I suggest removing `capistrano-rvm` entirely. That gem is very old, probably doesn't work with Capistrano anymore, and seems to be abandoned:

https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/issues/83

Comment: what version ruby and rails do you have?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference because Capistrano does not use the Rails gems at all. I tested with a Rails 5.0.6 and 5.1.4 and `cap install` worked fine for both.